# how to reset password on Instiki?

Tags: password-recovery

I have an install of [Instiki](http://www.instiki.org/) that I recently upgraded from v0.13 to v0.16.6. I need to reset the password, but can find no means of doing so. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help - From the [Instiki FAQ](http://www.instiki.org/show/FAQ):

> Q: Okay, so I forgot my password. Is
>   there any way to recover it? I’ve got
>   physical access to the box it’s on.
>   (Actually it’s installed on my iPod
>   Shuffle!) Someone please help.
>
> A: (0.10.2 and prior) rename the
>   latest snapshot to a .gz, gunzip it,
>   then look through it for password.
>   Ugly but worked for me.
>
> A: (0.11.0) Login to the db for your
>   system and look at the contents of the
>   “system” table. For sqlite3 (the
>   default), ”sqlite3
>   db/production.db.sqlite3” and then
>   ”.dump system”. I actually had the
>   issue when upgrading that there were
>   no rows in that table, so I inserted
>   one manually. ”insert into “system”
>   VALUES (1, ‘password’);”

Comment: Thx - I was easily able to read the password from the system table once I installed sqliteadmin, since it is stored in plain text (boo!).

Comment: No problem.  Yeah, doesn't seem like the ideal setup from what I was reading....